# How can i change my imageView constraint from viewcontroller. swift file

Tags: ios, swift

I have an imageview in the storyboard. It have width(375) and height(447) constraint . Now is it possible programmatically  to change my image view from View controller ?

Comment: Yes. Create an @IBoutlet for the constraint and change its `constant` property

Comment: @Paulw11 I had no idea that was possible! Do you just `control-drag` from the constraint itself in IB?

Comment: just create a @IBoutlet and also change constant but it's not working

Comment: You need to provide more information; edit your question to show your code. Do you get any constraint warnings in the console?